# Convert URL to normal windows filename Java

Tags: java, file, url, path, filenames

Is there a way to convert this:

```
/C:/Users/David/Dropbox/My%20Programs/Java/Test/bin/myJar.jar
```

into this?:

```
C:\Users\David\Dropbox\My Programs\Java\Test\bin\myJar.jar
```

I am using the following code, which will return the full path of the .JAR archive, or the /bin directory.

```
fullPath = new String(MainInterface.class.getProtectionDomain()
            .getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
```

The problem is, `getLocation()` returns a `URL` and I need a normal windows filename.
I have tried adding the following after `getLocation()`:

`toString()` and `toExternalForm()` both return:

```
file:/C:/Users/David/Dropbox/My%20Programs/Java/Test/bin/
```

`getPath()` returns:

```
/C:/Users/David/Dropbox/My%20Programs/Java/Test/bin/
```

Note the `%20` which should be converted to space.

Is there a quick and easy way of doing this?

Comment: Well, I tried using find and replace for the whitespaces and removing the first character, but I don't really like it. That's why I asked here, maybe someone knows of some way to convert it in a less error-prone and more efficient way.

Comment: Any alternatives on getting the full filename of the jar file are also appreciated.

Comment: @ David  are you meaning String WinPath = System.getenv("USERPROFILE");
                        WinPath = WinPath.replace("\\", "\\\\");
                        WinPath += "\\\\Desktop\\\\SalesReports\\\\";

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The current recommendation (with JDK 1.7+) is to convert URL → URI → Path. So to convert a URL to File, you would say `Paths.get(url.toURI()).toFile()`. If you can’t use JDK 1.7 yet, I would recommend `new File(URI.getSchemeSpecificPart())`.

Converting file → URI: First I’ll show you some examples of what URIs you are likely to get in Java.

```
                          -classpath URLClassLoader File.toURI()                Path.toUri()
C:\Program Files          file:/C:/Program%20Files/ file:/C:/Program%20Files/   file:///C:/Program%20Files/
C:\main.c++               file:/C:/main.c++         file:/C:/main.c++           file:///C:/main.c++
\\VBOXSVR\Downloads       file://VBOXSVR/Downloads/ file:////VBOXSVR/Downloads/ file://VBOXSVR/Downloads/
C:\Résume.txt             file:/C:/R%c3%a9sume.txt  file:/C:/Résume.txt         file:///C:/Résume.txt
\\?\C:\Windows (non-path) file://%3f/C:/Windows/    file:////%3F/C:/Windows/    InvalidPathException
```

Some observations about these URIs:

- The URI specifications are  [RFC 1738: URL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738), superseded by [RFC 2396: URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396), superseded by [RFC 3986: URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). (The WHATWG also has a [URI spec](http://url.spec.whatwg.org/), but it does not specify how file URIs should be interpreted.) Any reserved characters within the path are percent-quoted, and non-ascii characters in a URI are percent-quoted when you call URI.toASCIIString().
- File.toURI() is worse than Path.toUri() because File.toURI() [returns an unusual non-RFC 1738 URI](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6356783?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel) (gives file:/ instead of file:///) and does not format URIs for UNC paths according to [Microsoft’s preferred format](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows.aspx). None of these UNC URIs work in Firefox though (Firefox requires file://///).
- Path is more strict than File; you cannot construct an invalid Path from [“\.\” prefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). “These prefixes are not used as part of the path itself,” but they can be passed to Win32 APIs.

Converting URI → file: Let’s try converting the preceding examples to files:

```
                            new File(URI)            Paths.get(URI)           new File(URI.getSchemeSpecificPart())
file:///C:/Program%20Files  C:\Program Files         C:\Program Files         C:\Program Files
file:/C:/Program%20Files    C:\Program Files         C:\Program Files         C:\Program Files
file:///C:/main.c++         C:\main.c++              C:\main.c++              C:\main.c++
file://VBOXSVR/Downloads/   IllegalArgumentException \\VBOXSVR\Downloads\     \\VBOXSVR\Downloads
file:////VBOXSVR/Downloads/ \\VBOXSVR\Downloads      \\VBOXSVR\Downloads\     \\VBOXSVR\Downloads
file://///VBOXSVR/Downloads \\VBOXSVR\Downloads      \\VBOXSVR\Downloads\     \\VBOXSVR\Downloads
file://%3f/C:/Windows/      IllegalArgumentException IllegalArgumentException \\?\C:\Windows
file:////%3F/C:/Windows/    \\?\C:\Windows           InvalidPathException     \\?\C:\Windows
```

Again, using `Paths.get(URI)` is preferred over `new File(URI)`, because Path is able to handle the UNC URI and reject invalid paths with the \?\ prefix. But if you can’t use Java 1.7, say `new File(URI.getSchemeSpecificPart())` instead.

By the way, do **not** use `URLDecoder` to decode a file URL. For files containing “+” such as “file:///C:/main.c++”,  `URLDecoder` will turn it into “C:\main.c  ”! `URLDecoder` is only for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded HTML form submissions within a URI’s query (`param=value&param=value`), not for unquoting a URI’s path.

2014-09: edited to add examples.

Comment: Of course all this throws a god damn URISyntaxException.

Comment: Paths.get() uses the default filesystem so if you use it you can't test your code with an in-memory file system

Answer (score 17):

```
String path = "/c:/foo%20bar/baz.jpg";
path = URLDecoder.decode(path, "utf-8");
path = new File(path).getPath();
System.out.println(path); // prints: c:\foo bar\baz.jpg
```

Comment: this answer is dangerous. scroll down to @yonran's answer

Comment: you mean scroll up

Answer (score 3):

The current answers seem fishy to me.

```
java.net.URL.getFile
```

turns a file URL such as this

```
java.net.URL = file:/C:/some/resource.txt
```

into this

```
java.lang.String = /C:/some/resource.txt
```

so you can use this constructor

```
new File(url.getFile)
```

to give you the Windows path

```
java.io.File = C:\some\resource.txt
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It does not solve the incorrect (%20) representation of spaces. I guess those voting up are like the answer author; didn't read the question.

Answer (score 3):

As was mentioned - getLocation() returns an URL. File can easily convert an URI to a path so for me the simpliest way is just use:

```
File fullPath = new File(MainInterface.class.getProtectionDomain().
    getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
```

Of course if you really need String, just modify to:

```
String fullPath = new File(MainInterface.class.getProtectionDomain().
    getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI()).toString();
```

You don't need URLDecoder at all.

Comment: This is way simpler than the other answers and actually worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The following code is what you need:

```
String path = URLDecoder.decode("/C:/Users/David/Dropbox/My%20Programs/Java/Test/bin/", "UTF-8");
System.out.println(new File(path).getPath());
```

Comment: Thanks. This with .getAbsolutePath() is perfect.

Comment: The method decode(String) from the type URLDecoder is deprecated.It was better with new File()

Comment: @David you still need the decoding. Just use the proper arguments (as shown in my answer)

Comment: I have updated the answer with getPath which will never throw an exception and changed decode method to specify also encoding (that variant is not deprecated).

Answer (score 2):

Hello confused people from the future. There is a nuance to the file path configuration here. The path you are setting for TESSDATA_PREFIX is used internally by the C++ tesseract program, **not** by the java wrapper. This means that if you're using windows you will need to replace the leading slash and replace all other forward slashes with backslashes. A very hacky workaround looks like this:

```
URL pathUrl = this.getClass().getResource(TESS_DATA_PATH);
String pathStr = pathUrl.getPath();

// hack to get around windows using \ instead of /
if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS) {
  pathStr = pathStr.substring(1);
  pathStr = pathStr.replaceAll("/", "\\\\");
}
```