# Finding path of a file

Tags: java, file, path, space

ok so I am making a program where the user types a file name that is included in the jar file, so the program extracts that file from the jar then opens it.I have no problem doing any of this, there is just something weird that I don't understand here is the code I'm using:

```
String path=getpath(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
public void open(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("pdfs/"+filename);
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(path+"SultanKadab.pdf");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int length;
    while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0)
        os.write(buffer, 0, length);
    os.close();
    is.close();
if (pdfFile.exists()&&Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
         Desktop.getDesktop().open(pdfFile); //opening file
}

public String getpath(String f){
    String s = "";
    int lastInd=0;
    for(int i=0;i<f.length();i++){
        if(f.charAt(i)=='/'){s+="\\";lastInd=s.length()-1;}
        else if(f.charAt(i)=='%'&&f.length()-i>=2){
            if(f.charAt(i+1)=='2'&&f.charAt(i+2)=='0')i+=2;s+=" ";
        }
        else s+=f.charAt(i);
    }
    f=s.substring(0,lastInd+1);
    return f;
}
```

my question is about the getpath method, I don't think it is necessary, I think that java has a built in method to do that
getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath())="/C:/test%20test/"
it is converted to "\C:\test test\" so I can pass it to the fileOutputStream constructor
basically the getpath method changes the '\' to '/' and the %20 to ' '

Comment: I don't think you have to do that conversion. Java should handle the path you obtain just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Please see: [Get current working directory in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153337/how-do-i-get-my-current-working-directory-in-java)

The getPath method is not needed as Java provides methods to deal with paths.

Comment: dude the post doesn't say how to convert the %20 to ' ' I've read it all

Comment: Are you running getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath() in windows or linux? I'm getting forward slashes / when I use this.

Comment: I'm running it on windows, yes I'm getting forward slashes too.

Comment: Ok never mind I've found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164448/convert-url-to-normal-windows-filename-java
thanks for your concern :)